Fuzzy search in C#
I was asked to implement a FuzzySearch class in a C# project with the ability to change the degree of fuzziness.
It is to be used in a clinical setting where we get names with different linguistic backgrounds.
I have two methods and a class.
The first on is called LevenshteinDistance that calculates the Levenshtein-distance of two strings, the second on fuzzy searches a list of string where ratio of the fuzziness of 0.8 means that the difference between the word to find and the found words is less than 20%.
public static int LevenshteinDistance(string src, string dest)
        {
            int[,] d = new int[src.Length + 1, dest.Length + 1];
            int i, j, cost;
            char[] str1 = src.ToCharArray();
            char[] str2 = dest.ToCharArray();

            for (i = 0; i <= str1.Length; i++)
            {
                d[i, 0] = i;
            }
            for (j = 0; j <= str2.Length; j++)
            {
                d[0, j] = j;
            }
            for (i = 1; i <= str1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= str2.Length; j++)
                {

                    if (str1[i - 1] == str2[j - 1])
                        cost = 0;
                    else
                        cost = 1;

                    d[i, j] =
                        Math.Min(
                            d[i - 1, j] + 1,                    // Deletion
                            Math.Min(
                                d[i, j - 1] + 1,                // Insertion
                                d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost));       // Substitution

                    if ((i > 1) && (j > 1) && (str1[i - 1] == str2[j - 2]) && (str1[i - 2] == str2[j - 1]))
                    {
                        d[i, j] = Math.Min(d[i, j], d[i - 2, j - 2] + cost);
                    }
                }
            }

            return d[str1.Length, str2.Length];
        }

The search method
public static List<SearchScore> Search(string word, List<Patient> wordList,
        double fuzzyness)
        {
#if !LINQ           
            List<SearchScore> searchcore = new List<SearchScore>();

            foreach (Patient pat in wordList)
            {
                // Calculate the Levenshtein-distance:
                int levenshteinDistance =
                    LevenshteinDistance(word, pat.FULLNAME);

                // Length of the longer string:
                int length = Math.Max(word.Length, pat.FULLNAME.Length);

                // Calculate the score:
                double score = 1.0 - (double)levenshteinDistance / length;

                // Match?
                if (score > fuzzyness)
                {                                   
                    searchcore.Add(new SearchScore
                    {
                        score = Math.Round(score * 100),
                        patient = new Patient
                            {
                                CASENO = pat.CASENO,
                                FULLNAME = pat.FULLNAME 
                                //Other attributes
                            }
                    });
                }
            }
#else
            // Tests have prove that the !LINQ-variant is about 3 times
            // faster according to one of the developpers.
            List<string> foundWords =
                (
                    from s in wordList
                    let levenshteinDistance = LevenshteinDistance(word, s)
                    let length = Math.Max(s.Length, word.Length)
                    let score = 1.0 - (double)levenshteinDistance / length
                    where score > fuzzyness
                    select s
                ).ToList();
#endif      
            return searchcore;
        }

And the SearchScore class
public class SearchScore
    {
        public Patient patient { get; set; }
        public double score
        { get; set; }

    } 


The implementation looks fine, it does what it promises to do.
redundant comments
                // Calculate the Levenshtein-distance:
                int levenshteinDistance = ...

                // Length of the longer string:
                int length = Math.Max( ... )

                // Calculate the score:
                double score = ...

Please don't say it twice twice.
It's just distracting.
The code has already eloquently said it, no need for repetition in comments.
Elide them.
appropriate datastructure
The code says nothing about the ordering of each List.
If it required sorted lists, then the library routine might exploit binary search.
In general, most patients won't match the word target string,
so we should be striving to ignore, to not even look at, most patient names.
We call this "indexing".
Also, "word" isn't the best identifier here.
Consider incorporating "search", "target", or even "needle"
into your parameter name.
(The English idiom is to search for a needle in a haystack.)
database
Given a million patient names, we will probably want to store
them in a relational database, perhaps sqlite or postgres.
Interactive response time can be important to a UI,
which might ask several increasingly difficult queries
in hopes of quickly displaying relevant result(s)
and then fleshing them out over the next few seconds.
It might attempt exact match in the hopes of getting lucky,
then ask for increasingly fuzzier matches and continue
to populate the list on screen.
In the case of a dropdown chooser we might initially
display just the top match, and have a few seconds
until some user-initiated interaction which reveals subsequent fuzzier matches.
Select some K of around 3, and issue a DB query of exact match
on first K characters, then do fuzzy match on those.
Decrementing K on subsequent queries would expand the result set.
We can play this game with reversed patient names, as well,
in case the initial characters are less stable than a "-dottor"
or "-vych" or "-vich" suffix.
Store and process names in reverse order, so a prefix index
effectively becomes a suffix index.
As an independent item,
postgres
and other DBs offer fast indexed full-text search,
which you might prefer over a Levenshtein table scan.
memoize
In a long term relationship between clinician and patient,
there's a good chance that same typo will come up repeatedly.
For example an insurer might record "Mr. Smythe", and you can't fix their error.
Having laboriously computed matches of "Smyth" and "Smith",
it would be worth your while to store such results in a
database table, just in case we ever get a "Smythe" query in future.
Use timestamps on each record to help with cache invalidation.
Consider doing a batch recompute of cached results daily at midnight.
Probing for cache hit could be the UI's first query,
before it starts decrementing K.
